# Failed (NoSuchProviderException) to execute: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

Following is the `pom.xml` file of my Spring Cloud Server:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.org</groupId>
  <artifactId>config</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>config</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

This server uses a remote git repository with SSH Authentication. The `application.yml` file is as follows:

```yaml
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  profiles:
    active: composite
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        # https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#composite-environment-repositories
        composite:
          - type: git
            uri: file://${user.home}/local-config-repo
            defaultLabel: master
            search-paths:
              - roomie*
          - type: git
            # https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_git_backend
            uri: git@github.com:Org-Engineering/config-repo.git
            # https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_push_notifications_and_spring_cloud_bus
            clone-on-start: true
            strictHostKeyChecking: false
            # https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_git_refresh_rate
            refreshRate: 15
            # https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_default_label
            defaultLabel: master
            search-paths:
              - roomie*

security:
  provider:
    N=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider:
```

I'm using IntelliJ Idea as my IDE and when I try to run the application from the IDE the server works. On the other hand, when I do `mvn clean install` and execute the `.jar` using `java -jar ...` I get the following error:

```bash
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git@github.com:Org-Engineering/config-repo.git: DefaultAuthFuture[ssh-connection]: Failed (NoSuchProviderException) to execute: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
```

To try and overcome this error I added `security.provider.N` property in my `application.yml` file and also added a static block with `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());` in the main class. Nothing seems to work at this point.

Why am I able to run the application using the IDE and how can I make it work with the `.jar`. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the Java distribution I was using. It was fixed when I downloaded and replaced my JDK with [OpenJDK distribution](https://jdk.java.net/19/).

Answer (score 0):

`Jar` file by itself is useless - you need a full classpath to run an application.

To get the classpath all by itself in a file, you can:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>build-classpath</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>build-classpath</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
              <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/classpath.txt</outputFile>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

From: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Added this, but it's still not working